# Confirm location that .sublime-build is looking at (Sublime Text 3, C++) on Windows

Tags: c++, sublimetext3, sublime-build

I have a custom `.sublime-build` file in Sublime Text 3 (ST3), where I have included folder that I want it to search for a c++ header file:

```
{
"cmd": ["g++", "$file_name", "-o", "${file_base_name}.exe", "-I C:/package/armadillo74002/include", "-L C:/package/armadillo74002/examples/lib_win64", "-lblas_win64_MT", "-llapack_win64_MT", "&&", "start", "cmd", "/c" , "$file_base_name"],
"selector": "source.c",
"working_dir": "${file_path}",
"shell": true
}
```

However, when I run the script:

```
#include <armadillo>
```

I get the following error:

```
headerex.cpp:2:21: fatal error: armadillo: No such file or directory
```

but I can check My Computer and see that the file exists in that directory. Why is it giving me this error? What can I change so that it can find the header file I am looking for?

Comment: IIRC `C:package` searches from the current working directory of C, not the root.

Comment: @CaptainObvlious -- sorry, that was a mistake when I was typing the question. I've edited my question to reflect that my .sublime-build file is actually `C:/package/...`, rather than the `C:package/...` indicated in my question. I am still getting that error.

Comment: I don't know a huge amount about C++, but what if you change `#include <armadillo>` to `#include "armadillo.h"` (with or without the `.h`)? It's my understanding that includes in `< >` angle brackets are for files in the standard lib, while those in `" "` double quotes are in other include directories passed by the `-I` option.

Comment: @MattDMo -- Thank you so much for your help! While this does not answer my question above verbatim, it was the fix I was looking for. The .sublime-build was looking in the proper location, but for some reason I needed to use `" "` instead of `< >`. Making this change has allowed me to successfully call `armadillo`. If you'd like to add this as a solution, I'll accept it as the solution I was looking for, adding a comment why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not familiar with all of the terminology, as my experience coding in C/C++ is somewhat limited, but it is my understanding that there are two types of `#include`s. The first type, where the header file name is enclosed in angle brackets `< >` (`#include <stdio.h>`, `#include <string.h>`, etc.), means you are including a header from the standard library.

The second type, where the included file is surrounded by double quotes `" "` (`#include "Python.h"`, `#include "myheader.h"`, etc.), is for including any other header whose location is specified in the Makefile or on the command line with the `-I` option (at least for `gcc`). Subdirectories can also be shown - for example, if you pass the `-I/usr/local/include/mylib/include` option, your include statement might be `#include "x86_64/myheader.h"` if there are subdirectories in the original directory.

See [What is the difference between #include <filename> and #include "filename"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21593/what-is-the-difference-between-include-filename-and-include-filename) for a better explanation.

Since `armadillo` doesn't sound like it's part of the standard lib, and you're passing its location on the command line, it might be a good idea to replace the angle brackets with double quotes and see if that does the trick.